# asp.net c# Linq query to retrieve the sum of each value of a column

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, arrays, linq

I have the following array of TrackerReport Object:

```
public class TrackerReport : TrackerMilestone
{
    public long Views { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Id=" + MilestoneId + " | Name=" + Name + " | Views = " + Views;
}
```

I post also the parent class to better explain:

```
public class TrackerMilestone
{
    public int MilestoneId { get; set; }
    public int CampaignId { get; set; }       
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? SortIndex { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public bool IsGoal { get; set; }
    public bool IsPartialGoal { get; set; }
    public int? ParentMilestoneId { get; set; }
    public int? ViewPercent { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Id=" + MilestoneId + " | Name=" + Name + " | Url = " +  Url;
    }
}
```

So that it is displayed like this more or less:

```
ID    Name    Url    Counter
1      A     ab.com     5
2      N     ac.com     2
```

And I have a List of this object that I fill in this way:

```
var trackerReportList = new List<TrackerReport[]>();
foreach (var trackerItem in trackerChildren)
{
    //currentReport is the array of TrackerReport TrackerReport[] above mentioned
    var currentReport = GetReportForItem(GetFromDate(), GetToDate(), trackerItem.ID,
                                                 FindCampaignId(trackerItem));
    trackerReportList.Add(currentReport);    
}
```

All the entries have the same values, but the counter, so, for ex:
list1:

```
ID    Name    Url    Counter
1      A     ab.com     5
2      N     ac.com     2
```

list2:

```
ID    Name    Url    Counter
1      A     ab.com     17
2      N     ac.com     28
```

My goal is to generate a single TrackerReport[], with the sum of the counter values as counter.

TrackerReport[]:

```
ID    Name    Url    Counter
1      A     ab.com     22
2      N     ac.com     30
```

Is there any Linq query to do this? Or If you come up with a better solution, just post it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: well, a tracker is a guy for sure :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the `lambda expression` for your query.

```
TrackerReport[] trackerInfoList = trackerReportList
    .SelectMany(s => s)
    .GroupBy(g => g.MilestoneId)
    .Select(s =>
                {
                    var trackerReportCloned = Clone<TrackerReport[]>(s.First());
                    trackerReportCloned.Views = s.Sum(su => su.Views);
                    return trackerReportCloned;
                })
    .ToArray();
```

If you have noted, I have used `Clone<T>(T)` method to deep cloning one `object` by the grouped value. I could have done by copying each property, but I found it the easiest.

This is the `Clone()` method:

```
public static T Clone<T>(T source)
{
    if (!typeof(T).IsSerializable)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("The type must be serializable.", "source");
    }

    // Don't serialize a null object, simply return the default for that object
    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(source, null))
    {
        return default(T);
    }

    IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
    using (stream)
    {
        formatter.Serialize(stream, source);
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        return (T)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
    }
}
```

Before you continue, you need to set `[Serializable]` attribute on your `DTO` objects.

```
[Serializable]
public class TrackerReport : TrackerMilestone
{
    .
    .
    .
}

[Serializable]
public class TrackerMilestone
{
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Hope, this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to do it using Linq.

1. Firstly, you want to get the data in a single list rather than a `List` of `Arrays`. We can do this with a `SelectMany`.

   `trackerReportList.SelectMany(c => c)` flattens `List<TrackerReport[]>()` into `IEnumerable<TrackerReport>`
2. Then you group the objects by the relevant column/columns

   ```
   group p by new {
               ID = p.MilestoneId, 
               Name = p.Name,
               Url = p.Url} into g
   ```
3. Finally, you project the grouping into the format we want. `Counter` is obtained by `Adding` the `Views` for the collection of objects in each grouping.

   ```
   select new {
       ...
   };
   ```

**Putting it all together:**

```
var report = from p in trackerReportList.SelectMany(c => c) 
             group p by new {
                ID = p.MilestoneId, 
                Name = p.Name,
                Url = p.Url} into g
             select new {
                ID = g.Key.ID,
                Name = g.Key.Name,
                Url = g.Key.Url,
                Counter = g.Sum(c => c.Views)
            };
```

Comment: Tnx a lot, i saw this solution after I already tried the other

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it in the following way:
1) Let the `TrackerReports[] resultList` is the array of deep copies of the `trackerReportList[0]` items
2) As I understand, the Views property corresponds to the Counter column. If so, then

```
foreach(report in resultList)
{
    report.Views = trackerReportList.Sum(reports => reports.Single(r => r.MilestoneId == report.MilestoneId).Views);
}
```